# python parsing XML parsing attributes containing "xml" in the name

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml, xml.etree

I dont understand the following behaiviour.
I am parsing XML string by passing a string into XML eetree as follows:

```
from lxml import etree
mini_example = '''
    <body>
        <div facs="pre-publication" type="description" xml:base="/api/emi" xml:id="f877d62ae6e2c8ab4011c81c474217e0" xml:lang="en">
        <title desc="invention-title">Low tech high output PV</title>
        <head xml:id="_45a0fe0003">FIELD </head>
        <p n="0001" xml:id="_45a0fe0004">The present doc is about fooball</p>
        <head xml:id="_45a0fe0005">BACKGROUND</head>
        <p n="0002" xml:id="_45a0fe0006">Once upon a time</p>
        </div>
    </body>'''
parser = etree.XMLParser(resolve_entities=False, strip_cdata=False, recover=True, ns_clean=True)
XML_tree = etree.fromstring(mini_example.encode() , parser=parser)
paragraphs = './/p[@xml:id]'
heads = './/head[@xml:id]'
titles = './/title'
xml_query = '|'.join([paragraphs, heads, titles])
all_elements = XML_tree.xpath(xml_query)
```

When parsing the attributes of the elements I get:

```
for para in all_elements:
    print(para.attrib)
```

which results in:

```
{'desc': 'invention-title'}
{'{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}id': '_45a0fe0003'}
{'n': '0001', '{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}id': '_45a0fe0004'}
{'{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}id': '_45a0fe0005'}
{'n': '0002', '{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}id': '_45a0fe0006'}
```

So the attribute name "XML:"  gets transformed into "{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}".
Why is this happening?
and of course,what should I do? since I have multiple xml:id,xml:base, etc names of attributes.

Comment: I recently encountered this issue as well, using Python's built-in xml.etree.ElementTree instead of lxml.

Comment: The “xml” prefix is a reserved prefix and is bound to that namespace uri. What you’re seeing is the attribute name in Clark notation; the namespace uri surrounded by {} followed by the local-name. That’s the “why”, but I’m not sure what you mean when you ask “what should I do?”. Based on the why, do you need to do anything? How are you using this data? Are you only looking to get the local-name of the attributes?

Comment: With "what should I do " I mean how can I get the attributes in the dict with the {"xml:id":whatever}, {"xml:base": whatever}

Comment: You should use the expanded name in Clark notation to retrieve them: just as you would with any other attribute that's in a namespace, such as `xsi:type`.